# IE keeps destroying and recreating kerberos connections

Tags: internet-explorer, http, kerberos

How to keep a kerberos connection long-lived in IE 8? Here is what I observed (running browsers on MS windows server 2003):

- In IE8, if I make a request over kerberos connection to a server, it will automatically disconnect as soon as it gets back the response. The next request will open another connection, which obviously is very inefficient. The server does send back the Keep-Alive header in the HTTP response but it doesn't help.
- In the same IE8 browser, if I make a plain connection to the same server, the connections will stay connected.
- In firefox, the kerberos connection to the same server also stays long-lived.

So it's a combination of kerberos + IE that keeps the connection short-lived. Is there any IE/registry setting to ensure the connection is long-lived?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no Kerberos connection. You are talking about HTTP connections which are stateless, Kerberos security context is not.
2. There is no keep-alive with HTTP 1.1. All connetions are keep-alive by default unless a server sends a `Connection: close`.

Comment: Thanks.. By kerberos connection I mean HTTP connection with initial kerberos handshake. I know HTTP 1.1 is keep-alive by default, I added it to the header anyway just to be 100% sure it's not the cause.

Comment: Change your question please and forget about keep-alive. Any good server will ignore that.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but if someone stumbles on it, probable issue here is that server responding to these requests have global setting in IIS  "authPersistNonNTLM" set to False, what in effect makes IIS closing network socket connections (not HTTP) after each HTTP request that is Kerberos authenticated (forcing client to re-authenticate on new network connection), whereas this does not happen for NTLM authenticated HTTP requests by default.

Also, what cantonboy propably experienced is that Firefix was NOT using Kerberos authentication (since it doesn't have good communication with OS), but fallback NTLM authentication for all the requests, and thus succeeded (they look similar from HTTP chat standpoint, but work very differently). IE on the other hand will use by default Kerberos if computer/server/Kerberos is properly configured.